# Some Emails not Sent in Informatica Mapping (Java Transformation)

Tags: java, informatica

I have a mapping in Informatica BDM that sends emails based on credentials stored in an SQL table (subject, body, recipients, sender, etc.). Previously my source was a Hive table and my code worked as intended but now with the SQL source table not all records are sent through. Running the data viewer shows that the relevant data is where it's supposed to be in the mapping at run-time. Initially I thought the troubles were with the records containing no CC field but have recently discovered if I go back and delete the CC recipients field of records that are accepted then those emails are sent through

```java
//place our recipients into an array
String[] to_arr;
to_arr = recipients.split(";");//split on semi-colon in case there's more than one recipient

//place our CC'd recipients 
String[] copy_arr;
copy_arr = copy_recipients.split(";");//split on the semi-colon character

// Include our host smtp server 
String host = "my.server.ip.address"; 

Properties properties = System.getProperties();

properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

// Get the default Session object.
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

try{

    o_status ="MimeMessage not created";
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    o_status ="FROM not set";
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from_address));

    o_status = "TO not set";
    //add our recipients
    for(String receiver : to_arr)
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receiver));

    //add our CC'd recipients but make sure they exist first
    o_status="failed to add CC'd recipients";
    if(!isNullOrEmpty(copy_recipients))
            for (String rec : copy_arr)
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(rec));

    o_status ="Failed to set the subject line.";
    message.setSubject(subject);

    o_status ="Failed to set the body of the email.";
    message.setContent(body, "text/html");

    //transmit the message
    try{
        Transport.send(message);
        o_status = "sent";
    }
    catch(SendFailedException e){
        o_status= e;
    }
    catch(MessagingException e){
        o_status = e;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        o_status = e;
    }


}
 //incase the message can't be sent
 catch (MessagingException mex) {
        System.out.println("Failed to send message....");
         mex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here's the implementation of `isNullOrEmpty`:

```java
//checks if a string is empty or null
public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
        if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Any insight as to why an SQL table would behave differently than a Hive table in this given circumstance is much appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the mapping runs without any errors in the log file, making it difficult to debug as informatica bdm doesn't really have a strong Java debugger to begin with.

Here's a sample of my data 
[image]

Comment: You have almost empty catch blocks, you should at least log the exception message (and ideally a stack trace) in the problematic cases. Without it you're throwing away valuable information about the problem.

Comment: @JoachimSauer How would I write directly to informatica's logfile from a java transformation? something like [logInfo();](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/_transformation-guide_powercenter_10-0_ditamap/java_transformation_api_reference/loginfo.html) doesn't work

Comment: Also for clarification since informatica can't print to console from java I'm mainly using try-catch for stability not debugging

Comment: "Stability" is a strange way of saying "silently dropping errors with no way of knowing if stuff went right". I think you need to find a way to get debug and/or error information *out* of the system before you can reliably fix it. I don't know that environment at all, so I can only speculate. But something like a dedicated "exception" table sounds at least like a possible interim solution.

Comment: I certainly understand the importance of proper exception handling, but sadly as I have mentioned informatica BDM doesn't really have anything of the sort built-in. That's why you can see me updating the value of ```o_status``` throughout the code. It is unfortunately the best, yet extremely crude, way of achieving any form of logging for the time being. The java transformation can be pretty restrictive for what it allows you to do (it's not horrible by any means) because it's missing features and extensive support. That's typically why Informatica Dev's try to avoid them if possible.

Comment: then make sure that `o_status` includes *at least* the exception message in the exception case and ideally the whole stack trace, if that's your only logging mechanism.

Comment: The ```o_status``` now contains the exception message, but you gotta keep in mind that no exceptions are ever triggered in the first place